# Text spilling out of div - overflow: auto not working

Tags: html, css

if you go [here](http://ewsprojects.com/~lyons/new.php) and click on a thumbnail, and then on one of the tags, you'll see my problem. For the tags that have too much text and overfow, it's not putting in a scrollbar. I can't put a fixed width because the first part, the title, varies from one submission to the other.

Here's the css for the part that's supposed to put in the scroll when needed.

```
#scroll-pane{
left: -3px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
font-family:helvetica;
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;
}
```

Any ideas? I'm sure this is an easy question for you guys.

PeeHaa:

```
(function($) {
    $('#tag_info1').each(function() {
        var container = $(this);
        var total_height = container.height();
        var content_height = parseInt($('span.tag_title', container).outerHeight(true), 10) + parseInt($('span.tag_submission', container).outerHeight(true), 10);
        var p_height = 0;
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('padding-top'), 10);
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('padding-bottom'), 10);        
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('margin-top'), 10);
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('margin-bottom'), 10);  
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('borderTopWidth'), 10);
        p_height+=parseInt($('span.tag_submission_text', container).css('borderBottomWidth'), 10);

        $('span.tag_submission_text', this).height(total_height-content_height-p_height);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Tried to get it to work with mine, but to no avail :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The `overflow: auto` does work. It just isn't there.</strike>

You've added the `overflow: auto;` to the paragraph.

The paragraph doesn't know what the height is. If you add it to the container it will work.

Or give a height to the paragraph.

I've setup a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qDqBt/) which shows how to calculate the remaining height. To be able to set the correct height on your paragraph.

Comment: I think I'm missing something... I have it in my CSS. Do you mean it should be on some other element?

Comment: Oh, I see. What I want to happen is when the paragraph spills out, a scrollbar is added for just the paragraph part. Is this doable?

Comment: @MarkLyons sure as I stated in my question just give the paragraph a height.

Comment: The problem with that is that the first part (title and "submitted by") can a bunch of different heights and I want it to fit to the end if possible no matter the height.

Comment: @MarkLyons well since you are already using javasciprt why not calculate the height left with javascript?

Comment: Can it do that even if the height isn't defined, but just is that height because of padding and natural text height and stuff?

Comment: I am working on it now. I originally thought of this but I had no idea you could calculate height if there was no actual set height

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5947/discussion-between-mark-lyons-and-peehaa)

Answer (score 1):

I've no problem on Firefox.
But when you use overflow: auto; You must use it on the container, for example a div.

EDIT:
Ok, I understand your problem.
Currently you are using `height: 180px;` on the container. If you try something like `min-height: 100px;` and `overflow: auto;` on the text container, you can fix the size of the text container.

So your text container will have the same height but the container is extendable if the title is bigger.

I don't know if it's clear but if you want I can try to re-explain.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I just saw this playing around in Firebug. If you don't mind, could you look at my response to PeeHaa's question?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a `div` with `height` as well as `max-height` specified - it just wouldn't put a scroll bar even though `overflow: auto` was specified. It worked after I specified `min-height` in addition to the `height` and `max-height` values.